# Algorithm to find all linked objects that aren't a parent/grandparent/etc or a child/grandchild/etc

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have an object called `Device`. A `Device` can have **one parent** `Device`.  A `Device` can also have **n** child `Devices`.

I have a drop down list that shows all the selectable `Devices`. I can get all the `Devices` in the database quite easily - `db.Devices`.

The hierarchy can be infinite levels deep.

I need to get **all `Devices` that aren't above or below a given `Device` in the tree**. Essentially I'm asking for `Devices` unrelated to a given `Device` (neither a parent/grandparent/great grandparent/etc or a child/grandchild/great grandchild/etc).  I also need to exclude the given `Device` from the list.

What is the best way to do this? Should I use recursion?

(I am using C# and Entity Framework with an SQL Server database, so I can use Linq To SQL or use the model itself.)

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I'm not sure if you're asking for devices without a parent or children or if you're asking for devices unrelated to a selected device.

Comment: Does my edit clarify enough?  Essentially I'm asking for devices unrelated to a selected device (neither a parent/grandparent/etc or a child/grandchild/etc).

Comment: @link664 is that correct that you have multiple `roots` in your hierarchy?

Comment: What database are you using? Some (Oracle 11g, amongst others) support recursive queries, while some (mysql, for one) does not.

Comment: @dennis.solonenko Ummm... well yes.  Any `Device` that doesn't have a parent could be considered a `root`.

Comment: You say that the hierarchy is potentially infinitely deep -- I assume countably infinitely deep -- and that you want to get *all* of them. How do you plan on doing that, and what are you going to do with an infinitely large resulting data set? Is it *really* infinitely deep? I suspect that you are confusing *infinitely* deep with *arbitrarily* deep; those are two *completely* different things.

Comment: A `Device` may not (should not?) be a parent or child of itself - should a search for Devices not parent or child or Device1 include Device1 in the result?

Comment: @glowcoder - SQL Server, I have updated the question to include that info

Comment: Also - do you only want to exclude direct child / parent objects, or do you need to exclude all parent-of-a-parent related objects?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Yes I need to exclude the `Device` itself. And no, I want to exclude all parent-of-a-parent and all children-of-a-child related objects (as mentioned in the question - grandparents and grandchildren, etc).

Comment: If you have multiple roots in your hierarchy and any device is guaranteed to be included only in one tree, why don't you just add these roots to your model explicitly? Then this kind of filtering becomes trivial

Comment: @Dyppl doesn't resolve siblings that are not parent-child related, but do reside under the same hierarchical root.

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst: why? I meant that **all** devices under same hierarchical root should be tagged as "belongs to this particular tree, tree #5"

Comment: but you would still need to filter within that tree, which was my point - excluding other trees doesn't resolve the other elements within the search tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be first to get all of the siblings of the device `D`:

```
P = parent of the device
sibs = {all children of P that are not D}
```

Any descendants of any `d in sibs` is unrelated to `D`. Keep going up the family tree:

```
G = grandparent of the device
sibs = sibs union {all children of G that are not P}
```

Continuing this way, the set `sibs` and all their descendants is the set you're after.

In pseudocode:

```
D = device;
siblings = {};
while (D has parent) {
    P = parent(D);
    siblings = siblings union (children(P) \ D);
    D = P;
}
return descendants(siblings);
```

Comment: Would you do this in the database, or in code using EF? It's very logical but might not scale well with large hierarchies.

Comment: Your solution assumes that the topology is a single tree; what if it is a forest of trees?

Comment: @eric, anything on a disjoint component should be included, of course. the hard part is the stuff on the same tree.

Comment: I don't follow your train of thought. How are you planning on identifying the disjoint components?

Comment: In the database. Otherwise, there is no possible way to do it given just a single device. It's fairly easy to index components. This, to me, is not the interesting part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Denis - this depends on how your data is stored.

I'd suggest you implement your hierarchy using the [TSQL HierarchyId datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx). You can then very easily check if a row is a descendent of another row using [IsDescendent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203.aspx)

```
DECLARE @searchId HierarchyId -- select your id
SELECT @searchId = HierarchyId FROM Devices WHERE DeviceId = 1

SELECT * FROM Devices 
WHERE 
    -- not children
    DeviceHierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(@seachId) = 0
    -- not parents
    AND @searchId.IsDescendantOf(DeviceHierarchyId) = 0
```

**edit**

To briefly explain the HierarchyId datatype and how this would work, consider that each item has a place in a hierarchy under a root node. (If you have multiple natural roots, you would place each root under a super-root). Each hierarchyid column stores the complete hierarchical position of item. For example

```
Id | ParentId | HierarchyId
1 | null | \1
2 | 1    | \1\2
3 | 1    | \1\3
4 | 3    | \1\3\4
```

and so on. To check whether an item is a child of another, simply check whether the hierarchyId is contained within the other row's hierarchyId - e.g. 4 is a child of 3 because the entire `\1\3` is contained within it's hierarchyId `\1\3\4`, but 4 is not a child of 2 because `\1\2` is not contained within the hierarchyId.

To see whether an itemA is a *parent* of itemB, check whether itemB is a child of itemA.

Finally, you don't actually need to do any comparisons. The TSQL HierarchyId type contains a number of methods, one of which is the `IsDescendantOf` method that I've highlighted above. So a usage like `hierarcyId1.IsDescendantOf(hierarchyId2)` performs the kind of check that I've described here. The hierarchyIds are binary and are compared very quickly in the database.

I would use hierarchyId whenever possible when dealing with a database hierarchy.

Comment: I hadn't heard of that data type before.  Forwarded it on to my DBA in hopes that he will implement it and make my life easier!

Comment: The datatype already exists, you just need to implement the column to use it - each row needs to have its hierarchyid value calculated on insert or update.

Comment: Sorry, I meant implement columns to use it :)

Comment: Would I be correct in saying there is a lot of overhead in setting this up e.g. writing stored procs to insert rows in the hierarchy, especially if I am using Entity Framework as an ORM (which sadly doesn't handle this datatype yet)?

Comment: @link664 you can either insert with a stored procedure, or possibly create a before insert trigger to determine the hierarchyid. To retrieve the rows you would need to use a stored procedure. You are correct - EF doesn't handle this datatype, but to me it is an implementation that should be encapsulated in the database.

Comment: The issue however is, since EF doesn't handle that datatype, how would I get that information out to say display in a hierarchical tree view?  From the looks of other posts, it seems like some hefty adapter work.

Comment: I didn't realise that was part of the question! I just saw 'drop down list' and 'get all Devices that...' - this answer is useful for modelling hierarchy in the database which I thought matched your requirement. You'll still have the PK/FK relationship, of course...

Comment: All good, your answer provided an interesting take on the DB side of things anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on the parent, you could try

```
select * 
from devices as child 
where exists(select null 
                 from devices as parent 
                 where parent.id = child.parent)
```

My SQL isn't perfect, but that's the basic approach I would use.

Comment: This assumes that the parent-child relationship is one level deep.  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @jonfen the post was edited with clarification after I answered. (Actually a minute before I answered, but it was after I loaded hte page and formulated the post.)

Answer (score 0):

That depend on how you store your tree in the database. There is [nested sets model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) which allows to do such queries directly in the database.

Answer (score 0):

My knee-jerk algorithmic solution to this is a "mark-and-sweep" type solution (from garbage collector theory).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Na.C3.AFve_mark-and-sweep

Basically you traverse the entire hierarchy of devices and mark the ones that are "traceable", meaning that they can be "reached" through another device (using recursion).

Anything that is un-marked, you "sweep" for GC.  In your case, anything that is un-marked is the set you are looking for.

Comment: This is a bit vague - do you mean to check each item individually to see if it's related to the search record?

Comment: Interesting solution, although I would be wary of how that would perform when given a large tree.

Comment: Yeah, it was vague.  Maybe it's time for bed :)  I can't really get into the details without know the explicit data structure, but this answer was meant to be a nudge in the right direction.  Good call on the "HierarchyID Data Type".  I had never seen that before.  Looks very useful for tree structures in sql.